# How to join multiple select objects with javascript

Tags: javascript, select, join

I have three SELECT boxes with three different NAMEs, like

```
<select name="a">
  <option>something</option>
  <option>something</option>
</select>
<select name="b">
  <option>something</option>
  <option>something</option>
</select>
<select name="c">
  <option>something</option>
  <option>something</option>
</select>
```

Before sending the form, I would like to join the three selects into one, as my PHP script on the other side can only handle the object/array "a".

I thought it could work like like this:

```
  <input type="hidden" name="temp" value="" />
  <a href="#" onclick="document.formIndex.temp.value = \n
    document.formIndex.a.value.concat(document.formIndex.b.value,
    document.formIndex.c.value); alert(document.formIndex.c.value);
    document.formIndex.a.value = document.formIndex.temp.value;
    document.formIndex.submit(); return false" class="search_button">
    search
  </a>
```

But that doesn't work. Thanks for any tips what I should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give them the same name, and the browser will send three values with the same key to the server:

```
<select name="a">
  <option>something</option>
  <option>something</option>
</select>
<select name="a">
  <option>something</option>
  <option>something</option>
</select>
<select name="a">
  <option>something</option>
  <option>something</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Ah, gosh. I had that idea in my head, and then thought this surely would generate conflicts (I mean, honestly, in principle, this should generate an error message, no)? Thanks so much!

Comment: @luftikus143: No, having multiple elements with the same name is not an error, not even in the same form. Radio buttons actually have to have the same name to work. Note that using `document.formIndex.a` returns an array instead of a single element when you have more than one element with that name.